# IOS: UIImageView set border white radius and shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Here is my code for set the border, shadow and corner

```
// set border
[self.avatarImageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[self.avatarImageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];

// set shadow
[self.avatarImageView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeZero];
[self.avatarImageView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
self.avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;

// set corner
self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

If I only use the code for `set border` and `set corner`, it work well like this

[image]

But if I add the code `set corner`, I will got the result like this  (the border and corner radius work, but the shadow is gone)

[image]

However the code for set corner work perfect if it stay alone.
Please guide me what to do. Any help would be appreciate

**Update**
Follow @ozgur answer. Add 2 lines to my code, it will give a very beautiful view but the shadow is a little bit smaller

```
self.avatarImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.avatarImageView.bounds cornerRadius:10].CGPath;
```

[image]

Comment: what is `self.view`?

Comment: I copied your code and ran it. The image looks clipped to me. Are you sure you are not updating `masksToBounds` or `clipsToBounds` anywhere else?

Comment: @ozgur I'm sure don't update `masksToBounds` or `clipsToBounds` in another place

Comment: @ozgur sorry you, I confusion between `self.view` and `self.avatarImageView`, I have update my code and my picture

Comment: @ozgur you will see the shadow is gone

Comment: @PhanVănLinh try the example code in my answer below, see if it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rounded corners requires masksToBounds to be set to YES. Because of that nothing past the boundaries (like a shadow) can be shown, because it will be masked/clipped off. If you disable masksToBounds so that it will show then the rounded corners wont work because they are unable to mask/clip your image into the rounded shape because you disabled masksToBounds.

Therefor, you can't do both at the same time on one view—so you need TWO views.

You need to make a UIView the same dimensions as your UIImageView and make the UIImageView a subview of your UIView.

Then on your UIImageView set masksToBounds to YES, and on its' superview (the UIView with the same dimensions) set masksToBounds to NO and add the properties accordingly.

---

Change your code to this: (typed it all w/o using xCode so it's possible I have typos)

```
UIView *avatarImageViewHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.avatarImageView.frame];
avatarImageViewHolder.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[avatarImageView.superview addSubview:avatarImageViewHolder];
avatarImageViewHolder.center = avatarImageView.center;
[avatarImageViewHolder addSubview:avatarImageView];
avatarImageView.center = CGPointMake(avatarImageViewHolder.frame.size.width/2.0f, avatarImageViewHolder.frame.size.height/2.0f);


self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
avatarImageViewHolder.layer.masksToBounds = NO;


// set avatar image corner
self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

// set avatar image border
[self.avatarImageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[self.avatarImageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];

// set holder shadow
[avatarImageViewHolder.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeZero];
[avatarImageViewHolder.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
avatarImageViewHolder.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I use your code, I will get the result like the picture one in my post ( the corner radius not work)

Comment: @PhanVănLinh sorry I had a tiny typo in my code, I fixed it, now try.

Comment: Sorry for late respone. It work perfect now. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No need to take 2 UIView  or Subviews for applied corner radius  and border

Comment: @KanhaiyaSharma Are you sure? If you try to do rounded corner radius it will mask the shadow, if you disable mask it won't be rounded corner. As far as I know..

Answer (score 1):

You should update `layer.shadowPath` if you don't want the shadow to get clipped:

```
 self.avatarImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
 self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.avatarImageView.bounds cornerRadius:10].CGPath;
```

For this trick to work, `clipsToBounds` and his brother `masksToBounds` should be set to `NO`.

Thus, if you have an image whose size is greater than the avatarView's own bounds, you should define avatarImageView as plain `UIView`, create another imageView to display the image set its `masksToBounds` to `YES` and add it as a subview to `avatarImageView` so that you'll have a good cornered and shadowed view capable of displaying the clipped image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I post the result image to my question. I will use your solution for my project because it is beautiful but I will keep this question to find the way to make the shadow a little bigger

Comment: Also, you mention me to set the `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds` to NO, but if I set `masksToBounds = NO`. the radius don't work

Comment: @PhanVănLinh You should update the shadow offset if you want to make the shadow look bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a container view and move your imageview inside that container view, Use this code after doing so:

```
CALayer *imageViewLayer= self.imageView.layer;
imageViewLayer.cornerRadius= 20.0f;
imageViewLayer.masksToBounds= YES;

CALayer *containerLayer = self.containerView.layer;
containerLayer.borderColor= [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
containerLayer.borderWidth= 3.0f;
containerLayer.cornerRadius= 20.0f;
containerLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
containerLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
containerLayer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
containerLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.80f;
containerLayer.masksToBounds= NO;
containerLayer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:containerLayer.bounds] CGPath];
```

Feel free to tweak the settings as per your need. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `self.avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;` in `set corner`

Comment: I have set `self.avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;` in set `shadow`. Now I should change it to YES, or I need to add a new line code to `set corner`. Also, I tried to way above but it still won't work. the result image is as same as my second image in my post.